# Fluent NHibernate Conventions for CompositeIds

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a IIdConvention for my Fluent NHibernate mapping:

```
public class SplitIDNameConvention : IIdConvention
{
    public bool Accept(IIdentityPart target)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Apply(IIdentityPart target)
    {
        if (target.GetColumnName() == null)
            target.ColumnName(SplitName(target.Property.Name));
    }
}
```

This works perfect for tables with a single primary key, but I have a lot of tables with CompositeKeys. Is there a way to provide a Convetion which changes the mapped column name for CompositeIds in Fluent NHibernate?

Best regards,
  forki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not what you want to hear, but no, not currently.

Comment: Just to confirm, this is still true, right? I see there's an `ICompositeIdentityInspector`, but no way to manipulate its properties.